# Was this the appropriate action by this moderator?

Tags: discussion, moderators

I have had a few declined flags that, maybe in going back to them, someone could see the post differently.

But I had a flag declined recently, with a comment from the moderator, that concerned me a bit. Maybe I don't understand what would require moderator attention?

This *WAS* the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31899480/how-can-i-stop-this-infinite-loop-after-clicking

The person had posted a normal question at one point, but it had descended into nonsense in the comments, and then the OP started making edits in the post, I don't know why, adding things like this:

> "so i'm thinking i'll just tell you about my day. Went to the gym. Came back to my room. Smoked A HUGE BLUNT then watched Rush Hour 3"

I couldn't edit the post, it was locked. And since the post was real initially and there had been all the comment arguing, I flagged it for moderator attention and quoted that text as the reason.

But it was declined! and this was the message from the moderator:

> flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

**How does this content NOT require their intervetion?!**

Comment: The OP decided to delete their question and move on. It's already been a week. What do you want us to do? Also, I don't see any traces of it having descended into nonsense in the comments - there is not a single comment from the OP on this particular question, deleted or otherwise. You may have been thinking about a different post.

Comment: Where I live we are fine with blunt, size doesn't matter, peace ...

Comment: `The person had posted a normal question at one point, but it had descended into nonsense in the comments, and then the OP started making edits in the post, *I don't know why*,` well consider that *he's telling you why in literally the same sentence that you're quoting*, I have no idea why you have no idea why he posted what he did.  I don't know how he could have made it any clearer.

Comment: _I couldn't edit the post, it was locked_ - Was someone already editing it? If someone's already editing a post with obvious problems it's usually safe to assume they're taking care of it.

Comment: @BSMP It wasn't locked, it was deleted.  When you try to edit a deleted post it will say that you can't edit the post because it either locked or deleted, which is why he mistakenly thought it was locked.  If it was locked, it would be in the revision history.

Comment: I mean if it was deleted or changed by the time the moderator saw the flag, I understand that. I'm not asking about his decline, but rather the reason that was expressed, as if the content was acceptable. I would think discussing illegal activities would be unacceptable content in a post. Rather than leave it when I couldn't edit it, I flagged it. But I guess the feeling is there are other things to pay attention to so let things like this run their course?

Comment: What is illegal in the area where you reside isn't so everywhere (consider the US state of Colorado, for instance, where recreational marijuana is legal). The poster freely stated that the rambling statement was only added to add enough text that wasn't code in order to be allowed to post the question. If you actually read the text, it states that clearly: *The site is asking me to write more detail cause the code is too long*. There was no need for moderator intervention here; the post was poor, because it was a bunch of code without a clearly stated problem or a clear question.

Comment: It is legal where I live, and I don't bring it up out of it bothering me personally. But from a business stand point, I keep stuff like that off my websites because it may reflect poorly on the next customer that sees it. As a community I would think SO's best interests are our best interests, so I treated it as such. But the more interaction I have with moderators, the more I get the feeling they could give 2 shits because they are up to their ears in crap they don't want to deal with. 1000s of flags a day being one of those things.

Comment: And I CAN appreciate that feeling, you dont get it until you get enough rep to see the review queue. Then you suddenly realize why your old posts got down voted when you were new, people were sick and tired of seeing so much crap.

Comment: Questions about hacking and by-passing security restrictions are on-topic, no matter how illegal the actual act may be, we specifically burninated the [tag:legal] tag because questions on Stack Overflow should be expected to be answered by programming professionals, not law professionals. Legality of a questions contents have no bearing on how on-topic a question is.

Answer (score 15):

The post had this text at the bottom of it:

> P.S DO NOT READ NOT IMPORTANT. The site is asking me to write more detail cause the code is too long but i'm not sure what you may or may not need to help so i'm thinking i'll just tell you about my day. Went to the gym. Came back to my room. Smoked A HUGE BLUNT then watched Rush Hour 3

They clearly added what they thought was humorous filler so that they could get their question through the quality filters. There wasn't anything malicious or offensive about what they'd written, nor was it attacking anyone.

All that someone had to do was edit that out. You don't need a moderator for that, and there was nothing else for us to do there, so it didn't really require our intervention. In the future, if you see something like that, suggest an edit to remove it.

Comment: Although it's probably better to not actually edit that content out, as it's just such a strong sign that the question is very low quality; it makes it just that much clearer to the reader that they should just downvote and move on.

Answer (score 4):

The post was deleted by the author, and as such, there was nothing for the moderator to do.  Had the author not deleted the post (or if it should get undeleted in the future), you would have been able to edit it yourself to remove the inappropriate content, so even then there is no need for a moderator to be involved.